# Display a report based on an form application

Tags: forms, oracle, report, builder

I'm new in report builder, i would be very grateful if i get answers to my question.

After creating a form application , using oracle forms, now i would like to get a report using REport Builder that displays all the data generated by the application. 
Is there any way to get these data, without having to write from the begining all the procedures and functions in report buider.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Save the data generated by your Forms application into an Oracle table, then use this table as your source in Oracle Reports.